# Is there something to say about the irreducibility of polynomials and their derivatives?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Is there a relation between the irreducibility of a polynomial and its derivative under certain conditions?

Comment: Are you asking: when is the derivative of an irreducible polynomial itself irreducible?

Comment: Do you have some particular conditions in mind?

Comment: Are you talking about polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ or over any field/ring ? (So you're talking about formal derivative)

Comment: My question is not specific because I am not familiar with the topic and I have been unable to come up with things myself :(. I am interested in any result that links irreduciblity and the derivative (formal one over a general field).

Answer (score 1):

Very partial answer:

Any  polynomial $g(X)$ over the rationals $\mathbb Q$ (or more generally a field of characteristic $0$) with degree $\ge 1$ has antiderivatives $f(X)$ that are reducible.  In fact, given one antiderivative $f_0(X)$ you could take $f_0(X) - f_0(c)$ for any $c \in \mathbb Q$, which is divisible by $X-c$.

So having  $f(X)$ reducible doesn't tell you anything about whether $f'(X)$ is irreducible.

Of course, if $f(X)$ is divisible by $q(X)^2$ for some polynomial $q$ of degree $> 1$, then $f'(X)$ is divisible by $q(X)$.  If the degree of $f(X)$ is at least $3$, $f'(X)$ is then reducible.

Comment: I understand that there won't be a magical link between them (since if you look at the anti derivative, if it comes out reducible you can add $c$ so that it's irreducible (one of my previous question on this site)). I'm hoping that under some conditions lies a link. 

The reason I suspect that under suitable conditions this might be possible is because testing on wolfram alpha, the taylor expansion of e^x up to a certain degree seems to be irreducible.

Comment: Well, that would be a rather specialized result, and you should ask about it in a separate question.  You're unlikely to get a response from this very general question that sheds light on it.

Comment: But I'd love a generalized result :), in any case I'll take your suggestion and post the specific question later.